# Opening scene with a woman who gets her high heels stuck in a grate

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

This is a tough one. Does anybody remember a comedy back in the 80s (I think) in which, during the opening credits, we see a series of silly, everyday events (nothing to do with the movie's plot) set in New York.

The only one of those I remember is a lady in high heels walking along the sidewalk and getting her heels stuck in a sidewalk grate. As she's struggling to get her heels free, a guy comes along and tries to help her by pulling up on her feet.  But as he pulls up on her feet, he moves his hands up her legs and she fights him off with her purse.

Comment: Pretty sure I know what you're after, but are you sure you remember *nothing* else? The actors, the plot etc.?

Comment: Doesnt that happen in pretty woman?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the opening credits of [Stir Crazy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081562/combined), a 1980 comedy with Gene Wilder and Richard Pryor (and directed by Sidney Poitier!). They featured a few vignettes from New York, and one of them was the exact scene you've described (a woman's heel gets stuck in a grate, a man pretends to help her and cops a feel, and she hits him with her handbag). You can see it here around 1:50:

Comment: Thanks so much!  I remember seeing the movie and I remember those opening credits, but I didn't make the connection.